# Array of struct modify with pointer

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I wanna function to  modify each element of array of structure with pointer.

I am using two different size arrays

```
struct color 
{

    char red;
    char blue;
    int white;
};

struct colorInit
{

    char red;
    char blue;
    int white;
    int padding[60]; 
};


struct color batch1[30];

struct colorInit batchInitializd[30]; 

void modifystruct ( struct color *ptr)

{

  for ( int i = 0; i < 30; i++)

  {

     ptr[i].red = batchInitializd[i].red;

     ptr[i].white = batchInitializd[i].white;

     ptr[i].blue = batchInitializd[i].blue;

}

}
```

am i using pointer right way in the function ?

Comment: We are no "check my code" site. If you have a **specific** problem, provide a [mcve] and all required information. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> am i using pointer right way in the function ?

Syntactically speaking, yes.

The function will work fine if `ptr` points to an array of 30 or more objects. Otherwise, it will have undefined behavior.

The following is not valid any more since the OP changed the object type of `batchInitializd`.

<strike>You can simplify the function to:</strike>

```
void modifystruct(struct color *ptr)
{
   for ( int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
   {
      ptr[i] = batchInitializd[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: Please check the code now and let me know

Comment: @Damodaran, that's fine too.

Comment: ......................Thank you Sahu